# How efficient and scalable this idea from database designing perspective?

Tags: database, scalability

I'm working on a chat application with this feature:
People join and leave a group multiple times, can show only messages sent when their was inside the group.

The first solution that cane to my mind is to have members for each message who are the same as the chat members at the sending message time.

How much efficient and scalable is that solution?